# Monkey patching CKEditor to embed YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, monkeypatching

I'm trying to configure CKEditor so that it could embed YouTube videos directly... I saw there's a [proposed patch](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5184) but I want to keep the original CKEditor distribution as it is, so I was wondering if it's possible to "monkey patch" CKEditor at runtime so that if the user types a YouTube URL inside the Flash dialog, the URL gets transformed to allow embedding.

I've tried this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev){
    if (dialogName == 'flash'){
        var infotab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        var f = dialogDefinition.onOk;
        dialogDefinition.onOk = function(ev) {
            var cur = this.getContentElement('info', 'src').getValue();
            var newurl = cur.replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'youtube.com/v/'); 
            if (cur != newurl) { 
                this.getContentElement('info', 'src').setValue(newurl);
            };
            f(ev);
       }
    }
}
```

but it won't work, since inside `f` the code uses `this`, and my "patch" changes it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach the `onOK` to another property of `dialogDefinition`, `this` will be correct within it (I think).

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev){
    if (dialogName == 'flash'){
        var infotab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        dialogDefinition.oldOnOk = dialogDefinition.onOk; //change here
        dialogDefinition.onOk = function(ev) {
            var cur = this.getContentElement('info', 'src').getValue();
            var newurl = cur.replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'youtube.com/v/');
            if (cur != newurl) { 
                this.getContentElement('info', 'src').setValue(newurl);
            };
           dialogDefinition.oldOnOk(ev); //and change here
       }
    }
}
```

Or use [`Function.apply`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev){
    if (dialogName == 'flash'){
        var infotab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        var f = dialogDefinition.onOk; 
        dialogDefinition.onOk = function(ev) {
            var cur = this.getContentElement('info', 'src').getValue();
            var newurl = cur.replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'youtube.com/v/');
            if (cur != newurl) { 
                this.getContentElement('info', 'src').setValue(newurl);
            };                
            f.apply(this, ev);  //change here
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I had to add before the if line: var dialogName = ev.data.name; 
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;